# The view loading for a very long time when the location.back() called in the Angular application

Tags: angular, cordova

I have an cordova application. location.back() works very long on the device or in the emulator. Why? Is there a solution?

```
constructor(
  private location: Location
) { }

onClick(){
  this.location.back();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running outside the NgZone. Your code is obviously a simplification of what you are actually doing. To test if you are actually in the zone you can do this:

```
onClick(){
  this.location.back();
  console.log('In Zone:', NgZone.isInAngularZone()) 
}
```

If that logs `false`, you should check why you dropped out of the zone. Again, with the amount of code you posted this is impossible to determine. To check if it is indeed an issue with change detection, you can try this to see if it's faster:

```
// don't use this in production

constructor(
  private location: Location,
  private app: ApplicationRef
) { }

onClick(){
  this.location.back();
  this.app.tick();
}
```